# Error in appending two string pointers using strncat()

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcat

I've a function that is supposed to return a string with `char *first_str` & `char *N` appended

```c
char *append(char *N) {
    char *first_str = "first";
    return strcat(*first_str, *N);
}
int main(void) {
  char *N = "second";
  printf("%s", append(N));
  return 0;
}
```

It gives the following warning messages and segfaults at the end:

```
temp.c: In function ‘appendOneChar’:
temp.c:7:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strncat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    7 |  return strncat(*first_str, *N, 1);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |
      |                 char
In file included from temp.c:3:
/usr/include/string.h:133:40: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
  133 | extern char *strncat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src,
      |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
temp.c:7:29: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strncat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    7 |  return strncat(*first_str, *N, 1);
      |                             ^~
      |                             |
      |                             char
In file included from temp.c:3:
/usr/include/string.h:133:71: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
  133 | extern char *strncat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src,
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
Segmentation fault
```

So what's going on here?

Expected output:
`firstsecond`

Comment: `strcat(first_str, N)`.

Comment: Perhaps you **should read** the warnings, they tell you exactly what is wrong

Comment: `*first_str` is the same as `first_str[0]` which is a single character.

Comment: @Zakk it still segfaults for me

Comment: Then remember that `strcat` modifies the string pointed to by the first argument. And `first_string` points to a *literal* string, which is an array of `6` characters. Like any other arrays, this array can't be extended. Unlike other arrays, it's not allowed to be modified at all. You just can't use literal strings as destination, you must define your own array, and make sure it's big enough to fit both strings, *and* the null-terminator.

Comment: @3rdgrade-dropout Because `first_str` is local to `append()` function, and is a litteral string. Two-in-one sin.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So should I allocate memory then do strcat()?

Comment: @Zakk oh i thought the compiler will return then destroy the values held by the local variables

Comment: If you do, then you must remember to free that memory. And do an initial `strcpy` to copy the first string (or use `snprintf` to format the string). It's so much simpler to not use your function at all, and just use `strcat` or `snprintf` directly in your `main` function, and use sufficiently sized arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh no this was just for a quick demo, I was working on something else that incorporated strncat(). I'll look into the things you've said hm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To demonstrate, a working code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *append(char *N) {
    char *first_str = malloc(strlen(N) + 6); // 6 = strlen("first") + 1 (null terminator)
    if (first_str== NULL) {
        // malloc failed, handle error
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(first_str, "first");

    return strcat(first_str, N);
}

int main(void) {
    char *N = "second";
    
    char *concat = append(N);
    if (concat == NULL) {
      // append function returned an error
      return 1;
    }
    printf("%s", concat);
    free(concat); // Free the dynamically allocated memory
  
    return 0;
}
```

From the strcat manual: char *strcat(char *destination, const char *source)

Note: When we use strcat(), the size of the destination string should be large enough to store the resultant string. If not, we will get the segmentation fault error. That's why you need an array of size 12 (5+6+1), notice the +1 for  the '\0' that is stored in the end of the concatenated strings.

Note 2: You need malloc to allocate memory to the heap in order for the memory to remain until you use "free" to clear it. The variables you create within a function will be allocated on the stack and will be automatically freed when the function returns. So in your example when the function "append" returns the memory is no longer usable.